# Frequency for cells in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a **cell** in Matlab `A` of dimension `mx1`, e.g. `m=11`

```
 A={1 2 2 4 5 5 6 3 1 1 2}
```

Let `D` be the vector of unique elements in `A`, i.e.

`D=unique(A,'stable')`

that gives

```
D={1 2 4 5 6 3}
```

I want to find `C` that gives the number of repetitions of each element in `D`, i.e.

```
C={3 3 1 2 1 1}
```

I tried

```
count=histc(A,D);
```

but it tells me

```
"Error using histc
First Input must be a real non-sparse numeric array."
```

If I try to convert `A` and `C` in matrices using `cell2mat` it gives me

```
"Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."
```

Any idea?

Comment: `D=unique(A,'stable')` gives an error in my machine (R2015a). To apply `unique` and `histc`,  `A` must be a numeric vector (not a cell array of numbers). So use `A = [A{:}]` first. Also, the second input of `histc` should be non-decreasing. So instead of `histc` you can use `sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), D(:).'))`

Comment: Do you any other suggestion that does not require to transform A in a numeric vector? In my actual code, where each element of A is a number with 5 digits, doing A=[A{:}] produces a char 1x(total number of digits putting all numbers one next to another).

Comment: I also get an error when using `unique(A,'stable')` - though `cell2mat(A)` works perfectly fine for me. - perhaps you have different data in your cell than what you gave as an example? For example matrices/vectors with more than 1 element?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab recommended `histcount` instead of `histc`

```
a = cell2mat(A) ;
count=histcounts(a, max(a) - min(a))
```